# why does stopping an actor increases CPU usage?

Tags: akka, actor

In a chain of Akka actors, when a parent is stopped, it stops the child actors, but why does it increase CPU usage while stopping?

for exact reference go to this issue:

https://github.com/pranavkapoorr/AltaPay-Link_Service/issues/1#issue-366608337

many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe there is a bug in your code somewhere ?

Comment: I tried figuring out that even, do you have any idea what kind of bug could it be?

Comment: Taking a stack dump and look at the stack traces of the threads what your actors are busy doing is often useful.